# HTML5/Angular JS webpage keeps loading while signing in after immediate logout

Tags: angularjs, loading, html

We have an angularJS/html5 site. While trying to log in to the site immediately after logout causing the home page to keep loading continuously and it doesnot proceed further. After we close the browser and then try to sign in after some time the page loads properly.
Any solutions.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Router to change your view after logging in or out? In the example below, I called the router to take the user to /home (which should be defined in your routes) after logging out.

```
logout(): void {
    //do other logout stuff here
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

You can view the documentation here:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html